# Неправильное выполнение клика через SendInput

Tags: c++, winapi

Программа неправильно выполняет клик по чекбоксу в Firefox. В результате через SpyXX обнаружил, что при программном клике посылаются 3 команды `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, `WM_LBUTTONUP`, `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK`, а при реальном только `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`. Нажатие выполняю с помощью HoldMouse. Подскажите, почему кнопка может "сразу отжиматься"?

```
AIMOUSE_API void __cdecl HoldMouse(int x, int y, MouseButton button) {
    INPUT Input;
    Input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    memset(&Input, sizeof( Input ), 0 );
    Input.mi.dx = x;
    Input.mi.dy = y;
    switch (button) {
    case AIMOUSE_LEFT:
        Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
        break;
    case AIMOUSE_MIDDLE:
        Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN;
        break;
    case AIMOUSE_RIGHT:
        Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN;
        break;
    }
    SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

Comment: Что возвращает  `SendInput`?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить флаг `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE`

Comment: Дополнительно к размышлению http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819889/mouseeventf-absolute-doesnt-work

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Ошибка оказалась в другой программе, которая использовала текущую DLL для действий мышки. Ошибка была банальна - там дополнительно вызывалась функция click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка связана с моей невнимательностью. В другом месте дополнительно вызывалась функция с отправкой (HoldMouse и ReleaseMouse).